# cannot find symbol - method fillArc(int,int,int,int,int,int)

Tags: java, awt

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;



/**
 * object of class myComponent provide a "canvas" to record your art work.
 *
 * @author (Kevin Knapp)
 * @version (9-27-13)
 */    
public class MyComponent extends JComponent
{

    /**
     * method used in awt to "paint" on the component
     *
     * @param  g   graphics used to "paint" with
     * @return     none
     */
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        // declares the 2D Graphics object and a Rectangle
        Graphics2D g2;


        Ellipse2D.Double outerFace = new Ellipse2D.Double(100,150,300,350);
        Line2D.Double mouth = new Line2D.Double(200,400,300,400);
        Ellipse2D.Double leftOuterEye = new Ellipse2D.Double(150,275,50,50);
        Ellipse2D.Double rightOuterEye = new Ellipse2D.Double(250,275,50,50);
        Ellipse2D.Double leftPupil = new Ellipse2D.Double(150,285,25,25);
        Ellipse2D.Double rightPupil = new Ellipse2D.Double(250,285,25,25);
        Line2D.Double leftEyeLine = new Line2D.Double(150,300,200,300);
        Line2D.Double rightEyeLine = new Line2D.Double(250,300,300,300);


        leftPupil.fillArc(75, 100, 200, 200, 90, 270);

        rightPupil.fillArc(75, 100, 200, 200, 90, 270);


        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.draw(outerFace);
        g2.draw(mouth);
        g2.draw(leftOuterEye);
        g2.draw(rightOuterEye);
        g2.draw(leftPupil);
        g2.draw(rightPupil);
        g2.draw(leftEyeLine);
        g2.draw(rightEyeLine);
    }
}
```

So I would assume the error means that fillArc isn't a method listed in the classes I've imported, but I've checked the API and its there, and I also checked the spelling of the classes, so Idk what to do

I have circles for the pupils of the eyes as reference point for the arcs I want to fill in, but I cant even play with positioning until I get something to show up.

Comment: format your code better please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `fillArc()` method in the `Ellipse2D.Double` class. Probably you should call this method on the `Graphics` object:

```
g.fillArc(75, 100, 200, 200, 90, 270);
```

Comment: i feel so dumb lol, but i did just learn this 2 days ago, thanks, ill go read up some more since i dont understand the g and g2 stuff yet